# Return result from another apicontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm trying to call the **Get** method in my **CategoryController** from my **WareController**. How would I do that.

I've tried this in my **WareController**

```
// GET: api/Ware?category=5
    public List<WareDTO> GetByCategroy(int id)
    {
        BLLServiceGateway<List<WareDTO>> gate = new BLLServiceGateway<List<WareDTO>>();
        var item = gate.Get(path + "?category=" + id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return item;
    }

public IHttpActionResult ViewItems(int id)
    {
        var model = new WareModel()
        {
            wares = GetByCategroy(id),
            currentCategory = Redirect("api/category/" + id) /// This is were I want to get the category object
        };
    }

        return Ok(model);
```

and my **CategoryController** looks like this

```
// GET: api/Categories/5
    public CategoryDTO Get(int id)
    {
        BLLServiceGateway<CategoryDTO> gate = new BLLServiceGateway<CategoryDTO>();
        var item = gate.Get(path + id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API controller are just classes, so you easily can do this:

```
currentCategory = new CategoryController().Get(id);
```

But there may me problems if you want to deal with context.